# Ploting a GIF from a single data file

Tags: gnuplot

Hello guys I am new to gnuplot and im looking to plot a gif representing the evolution of some probabilities with cycles. 
My data file is structured like this:

```
0   0   1   3.56133e-008    2   1.18619e-007    3   3.75373e-007 ...
0   0   1   3.56133e-008    2   2.26246e-008    3   1.44814e-007 ...
```

The first row represents cycle 0 while the first and second column represents position 0 and its probability. The number of positions is large so doing it manually will take too much time.

I got this for now but i dont really know how to do the for loop with this kind of data.

```
set terminal gif 
set output 'Probability.gif'
stats 'Probability.txt' nooutput
set xlabel 'Position'
set ylabel 'Probability'
set yrange [0:1]
set style fill solid border -1
unset key
```

Thanks beforehand any help is apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to extract all x and y pairs from each row and plot it into a table. Actually, gnuplot prefers to have data in columns. Then plot this table to the gif terminal with the option `animated`. Check `help gif`. If you have a file remove the datablock `$Data <<EOD ... EOD` and in the code replace (2 times) `$Data` by `"YourFilename"`.

**Code:**

```
### animated rows x0 y0 x1 y1 x2 y2
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0 0.00   1 0.10   2 0.20   3 0.40   4 0.20   5 0.10   6 0.00
0 0.00   1 0.08   2 0.18   3 0.48   4 0.18   5 0.08   6 0.00
0 0.00   1 0.05   2 0.16   3 0.58   4 0.16   5 0.05   6 0.00
0 0.00   1 0.08   2 0.18   3 0.48   4 0.18   5 0.08   6 0.00
0 0.00   1 0.10   2 0.20   3 0.40   4 0.20   5 0.10   6 0.00
EOD

stats $Data nooutput
ColCount = STATS_columns
RowCount = STATS_records

set xrange[0:6]
set yrange[0:1]

set terminal gif size 400,400 animate delay 50 optimize
set output "myAnimation.gif"

do for [j=0:RowCount-1] {
    set table $Extract
        plot for [i=1:ColCount/2] $Data u (column(2*i-1)):(column(2*i)) every ::j::j w table
    unset table
    plot $Extract u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lw 2 title sprintf("Row %d",j)
}
set output
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]